# How to pass runId to glue job triggered by workflow from lambda? (Python)

Tags: python, pyspark, aws-lambda, aws-glue

Currently I am aware that you can pass arguments directly to a glue job if you trigger it directly with `start_job_run()`. However, what if I want to trigger a workflow that subsequently triggers the job but does some initial stuff first? I believe I can set workflow properties, but in order to retrieve them with `get_workflow_run_properties()`, I need to have name (easily done) and  runId (not easily done) as arguments, which is kind of a catch 22.

My trigger code:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    glue_client = boto3.client("glue")
    workflow_name = os.environ["workflow_name"]
    try:
        response = glue_client.start_workflow_run(Name=workflow_name)
        run_id = response["RunId"]
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(e)
    try:
        response = glue_client.put_workflow_run_properties(
        Name=workflow_name,
        RunId=run_id
        RunProperties={
            'runId': run_id,
            'someOtherParameter": "12345"
            }
        )
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(e)
```